# Toolbar not locking to bottom of screen, Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, toolbar

I am having a bit of trouble getting the toolbar to lock to the bottom of the screen, does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select toolbar and add constraints like this:
[image: Constraints]

Comment: Hi, added the missing constraints and it worked however now the segmented control and refresh button sits too far left on the toolbar, leaving a gap on the simulator, which isnt visible when editing the story board :( Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesPatterson try lift mapview and add zero constraint to bottom of mapview

Comment: I tried this but no luck :( Have submitted new question for this problem, will accept your answer for this one. Thanks a lot for your help